# How do I use Glide with GridView? (Android/Kotlin)

Tags: android, gridview, kotlin, android-glide

I have successfully constructed a `gridView` using this code:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    var inflater = mContext!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    var row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_cell, null)  

    row!!.glide_img_cell_id.setImageResource(R.drawable.cookie_icon_60)

    return row
}
```

It returns the test image as it should in the `gridView`
However, my real image data comes from `urls` so I'm using `Glide`. I have already done a check with my real data using `Glide` and it works fine. However, I can't seem to get it to work in my `GridView`. This is my altered code:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    var recipe = this.recipeArray!![position].recipeImage
    var inflater = mContext!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    var row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_cell, null)  

    row!!.glide_img_cell_id.loadImageUrl(recipe) as GlideImageView

    return row
}
```

I'm doing the same thing except that I now use `Glide`. Also, another thing I'm confused about is `convertView`. Some tutorials I've watched use it, others don't. What is it? Obviously I didn't need it in my first example as it worked.

***UPDATE***
Casting to `GlideImageView` the app crashes with `kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to com.bumptech.glide.Glide`, without casting it simply does not show anything.

***UPDATE2*** 
As suggested, I changed the code to the following, but the app is still blank and shows nothing:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var recipe = this.recipeArray!![position].recipeImage

    var inflater = mContext!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    var row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_cell, null)  
    Glide.with(mContext).load(recipe).fitCenter().centerCrop().into(row!!.glide_img_cell_id)

    return row
}
```

Does this seem right?

***UPDATE***
Still haven't solved this. Have looked into the xml file that should contain the image. Looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/glide_img_cell_id"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
```

Have also used `<com.master.glideimageview.GlideImageView` instead of `<ImageView` but still nothing.

Have also tried this:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var recipe = this.recipeArray!![position].recipeImage

    var cv = convertView
    var test = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
    cv = test.inflate(R.layout.image_cell, parent, false)

    Glide.with(this.mContext).load(recipe).into(cv!!.glide_img_cell_id as ImageView)

    return cv
}
```

...which is similar. But that doesn't work either. Don't know why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it now: Used `Picasso` instead. Did the exact same thing. :/

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your adapter.

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .fitCenter()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageview);
```

Comment: Like this? `        Glide.with(mContext).load(recipe).fitCenter().centerCrop().into(row.glide_img_cell_id)` didn't work. Could you elaborate or show what the adapter should look like? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope its help you.

```
Glide.with(this).load(recipe).into(row!!.glide_img_cell_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, but can't use `this` since the class is not an activity. I need the context passed from the activity...

Comment: You just pass the context in the constructor  and you can use it.